# My garage has a GFI wall plate, with both buttons in center, but has no outlets

Tags: wiring, garage

Plate is solid at top and bottom, where outlets would be. Can this be replaced with normal gfi receptacle?

Answer (score 5):

That's a "deadfront" GFCI. Probably for the garage door opener circuit, since the garage door opener outlet is too high to reach for resetting.

While you *can* replace it with a normal GFCI (if you are careful about which wires are "line" and which are "load" when doing so) it may not be *wise*, depending on how much power the garage door opener needs, and what else you intend to plug in.

Answer (score -5):

The easy way to do this is to leave everything in place and plug an extention cord into the receptacle in the ceiling. Loop the cord around the support for the opener motor as a strain relief.

Comment: Wow! what is wrong with using the duplex receptacle in ceiling for general use? Would it be OK if one of those spring loaded reel extension cords was plugged into the overhead receptacle? Or if a hook would be screwed into the joist next to the overhead receptacle and the extension cord secured properly to that hook as a strain relief?

Comment: Seems to be not answering the question. What "duplex receptacle in ceiling"? What opener? Did you maybe misread Ecnerwal's answer as the question?

Comment: @Ecnerwal referred to a garage door opener. The usual way to power these is with a duplex receptacle in the ceiling of the garage. I took it from there. The OP did not refer to a garage door opener and has not added any info since posing the question. I wuld like to haqve the OP tell us more details.